# date picker appear when button click

Tags: objective-c, ios7, datepicker

I am a trainee of IOS development. I have a button , when I click the button date picker should appear, in that date picker I need cancel and done bar button. when I click done date should appear on my text field (by programatically). help me

```
-(void)calbtn:(id)sender{
    pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];
    picker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    picker.hidden = NO;
    picker.date = [NSDate date];
    [self.view addSubview:picker];


    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];
    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];
    [doneBtn setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:50.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [doneBtn setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:50 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

     [barItems addObject:doneBtn];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];
    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:picker];
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];
```

how to set frame for done and cancel bar button.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This community isn't typically used for "give me an answer" as much as it is "why is my code not working".

Answer (score 0):

Just use an UIActionSheet with a datepicker inside and bar on top of it with the buttons you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create AccessoryView using UIToolbar with UIBarButtonItems of Done and Cancel. and add  input accesary view for text field

```
     [cellTextFeild setInputAccessoryView:fieldAccessoryView];
```

and then take pickerview add it on view and add it as input view for textfield.

```
     [cellTextFeild setInputView:pickerBGView];
```